# C# Thread synchronization (waiting executing)

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

Is it possible to call ShowDialog(), but to create dialog window under main form, not on the top?

I'm calling ShowDialog because I want to stop executing the main program.

I don't need the dialog window, because I will create many dialogs from threads and they will prevent each other.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? It sounds like you are doing a multithreaded app, and need to control thread execution. There are mechanisms such as mutexes and semaphores to do this.

Comment: hm.. i all explaine in question, may be my english is poor

Comment: Question is not clear to me...

Comment: Very confusing question to me. Can you do some better explanation. Write pseudo code or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read synchronization of threads. For stopping executing code use [`EventWaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) object.

Instead of creating and show dialog call `WaitOne()` of `EventWaitHandle`:

```
private static EventWaitHandle ev;
//...
[MTAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    //...
    ev = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
    //...
    ev.WaitOne(); //Stop execution
    //...
}

//Another thread function.
public static void ThreadProc()
{
    //...
    ev.Set(); //Continue execution of Main
    //...
}
```

A good example is on MSDN. Also note, that you need to call `Reset()` before using blocking again or create `EventWaitHandle` with `EventResetMode.AutoReset` option (read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventresetmode.aspx)).